# What symbols have to be escaped in cmd.exe command line?

Tags: windows, shell, cmd, command-line-arguments

I've trouble with finding a list of all symbols that need to be treated specially in Windows cmd.exe command line.

For example,

```
C:\Users\boda>echo ">"
```

Outputs:

```
">"
```

But

```
C:\Users\boda>echo '>'
```

Doesn't output anything.

Similarly none of these work:

```
C:\Users\boda>echo \'>\'

C:\Users\boda>echo \'\>\'

C:\Users\boda>echo '\>'
```

There are similar issues with characters `|` and `^` and probably more.

Does anyone know how to use raw strings in cmd.exe?

Answer (score 5):

These links might help you out!

http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html

http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php

Comment: @bodacydo please mark as answared, so everyone will be confident that it is the answare